# Why isn't my Batch file opening when windows start?

Tags: batch-file, registry, startup, registrykey

The batch I created is intended to start a Python file, and for reasons of dependency with Python and Geckodriver, I have no way to work with the Batch file directly in the Startup folder, for this reason I need to work with registries.

I entered the following key in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` path:

[image]

But for some reason the Batch file associated with the key does not open when Windows starts. I already checked everything, the Batch file works perfectly when executed manually and path in the key value is totally correct. It is not working on `RunOnce` either. I also checked the `Startup` tab in the Task Manager and it is enabled. Does anyone know what could be happening? why is the file not working?

Comment: What is the exact full-filename of the batch file?

Comment: @Magoo `TestStartup.bat` is the Batch file name

Comment: I asked for the FULL filename - that is including path.

Comment: @Magoo `C:\GitHubProjects\AmauterProject\TestProject\TestStartup.bat`

Comment: Try a line like `>filename echo %time%` just after the `@echo off` in `teststartup.bat` to see whether the file is created, which will indicate whether the problem lies with the starting of the batch or the running.

Comment: @Magoo I tried to do what you said and when I manually run the Batch file, a new file is created as it should happen, but when I restart Windows, it does not create the file, which means that it simply did not run

Comment: Try to precede the path with `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C`…

Comment: @aschipfl I tried what you said and added your line at the beginning of the key value, but it didn't work. A curious thing that I realized is that none of the other 3 keys above in the image seem to be working either, none of them starting when Windows starts, now I'm scared, maybe there is something that is preventing the registries from working?

Comment: Alright, so I believe that you have some policy in place preventing the listed startup programs to run…

Comment: The majority of the things which could cause your issue are outside of the scope of this site, which deals only with issues with your code, not with your Operating System, its setup, or its installed software. Your question should be deleted and posted on another site, which deals with software issues. I would ask that you specifically check the path of the `TestStartup.bat`, because you definitely have at least one spelling error in there, `amateur` is the correct spelling, therefore your directory should normally be named `AmateurProject`, not `AmauterProject`.

Comment: Incidentally, you don't need any of those programs to run at startup, so I'd advise that you remove the `ApowerREC`, `CCXProcess`, and `Opera Browser Assistant` values. If you really feel that your issue lies with the batch file, and not your system or software, then you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65244824/edit), to include the entire content of that batch file. Please remember though, that you've already indicated that none of the other value data entries are run, which implies that your issue lies elsewhere; _hence why I feel your question is off topic here_.